# Getting a feed of posts with filtering posts from blocked users in a efficient way using Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React application with a feed of posts, and I've implemented user blocking. When a user blocks another, I want to filter out posts from blocked users in the feed. I want to know whether my implementation or structure needs to be changed to make it more efficient.

I have the following structure inside Firestore

```
posts collection
users collection -> user document -> blockedUsers collection
```

The current implementation look like this.

```
const Feed = ({ currentUser }) => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const postsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('posts');

    postsRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const allPosts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      const filteredPosts = allPosts.filter((post) => {
        const isBlocked =
          currentUser.blockedUsers && currentUser.blockedUsers.includes(post.userId);
        return !isBlocked;
      });

      setPosts(filteredPosts);
    });
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.id}>
          <p>{post.text}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is there a better way I can do this with more efficiency? As I have to go through every post to see whether the user is inside my block list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the [`not-in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in)? That'd allow you to exclude the posts from up to 30 users with a query.

If there are more than 30 blocked users, you will have to post-filter the others in your application code - as you already do.